# Search box in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, search, plugins, feeling-lucky

Is there a plugin to Chrome that adds a separate search box?

I'd like to set the address bar as 'feeling lucky' search, and a separate box for google search. What's especially important to me is having two keyboard shortcuts like in Firefox: Ctrl-K to search, Ctrl-L to feel lucky.

Comment: Should be renamed to: Feeling Lucky in Chrome

Comment: No, there is a solution to achieve Feeling Lucky from the address bar. My problem is that I want two separate boxes - one for lucky and another for search.

Comment: May I ask why? Given that search results appear as you type, I can't find fault with the current single box setup. YMMV, of course.

Comment: It's just more convenient to me this way, I'm used to ctrl-k for search, ctrl-l for lucky.

Comment: If Google Chrome can't do that, maybe Autohotkey (which is Windows only) can help you. Anyway I prefer to use just Google Browse By Name

Answer (score 8):

The address bar *is* the search bar. Here's a solution I made:

1. Go to [Spanner] > Options > Basics > Default Search > Manage
2. Click Add
3. Enter this url for URL:

   {google:baseURL}search?{google:RLZ}{google:acceptedSuggestion}{google:originalQueryForSuggestion}sourceid=chrome&ie={inputEncoding}&q=%s&btnI=I'm+Feeling+Lucky
4. Set as default

This should make your default search provider the I'm Feeling Lucky service. I have several search providers (keywords are excellent in Chrome, entering "php substr" takes me to the php.net site and tells me while I'm typing I'm using the PHP search engine).

Answer (score 4):

There is a "trick":

You can add a custom search engine, you have to use the "Feeling lucky" as another engine:

Follow the directions described  [here](http://www.chromeplugins.org/tips-tricks/custom-search-engines-in-google-chrome/):

Use:

**Name:**Feeling lucky

**Keyword:**fl

**URL:**http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%s&btnI=I'm+Feeling+Lucky

and then you can type:

<kbd>F</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd>*Your term*<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

And it will take you there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the search in the "new tab". I don't think plugins are supported yet...

Answer (score 0):

There is no official or unofficial plugin for "new search box" released yet. A [quick google search](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&ei=bsxdSuPhPKXW6gOYkeH_DQ&sa=X&oi=spell&resnum=0&ct=result&cd=1&q=new+search+box+plugin+for+chrome&spell=1) suggest the same :)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is a bookmarklet:

```
javascript:q = "" + (window.getSelection ? window.getSelection() : document.getSelection ? document.getSelection() : document.selection.createRange().text); if (!q) q = prompt("You didn't select any text.  Enter a search phrase:", ""); if (q!=null) location="http://www.google.com/search?btnI=&q=" + escape(q).replace(/ /g, "+"); void 0
```

Create a new favourite and replace the url with the code above. Click on the bookmark to search.