# Google is too slow to load

Tags: html, google-search

Using Google as my browser's homepage has become unbearably slow. (Let's just assume I have a slow Internet connection.)

I want to create a simple HTML page that I can keep local to my machine that contains a simple HTML form that will submit a query to Google. -- I want to use this as my browser's homepage in lieu of "about:blank"

Could an enterprising SuperUser help me create the HTML to help me make this dream a reality?

Comment: Looks like I'm being lazy.

Comment: Are you referring to the "regular" Google web search page, http://www.google.com, or iGoogle, http://google.com/ig, and presumably with any number of gadgets as your homepage?

Comment: First time in my life I have ever heard someone say google was slow.

Comment: @Danny I was referring to google.com. It easily takes me 3 seconds to load here at work and its auto-focus-on-the-search-bar became unbearable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Save the page using your browser's save-complete-page functionality, and then set an HTML "base" tag in the header of the saved page to google.com.

Info on that tag here: http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_base.asp

Answer (score 8):

Set your homepage to about:blank and then use the search bar of your browser.

Answer (score 5):

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form action="http://google.com/search" name=f><input name=hl type=hidden value=en><input autocomplete="off" maxlength=2048 name=q size=55 title="Google Search" value=""><br><input name=btnG type=submit value="Google Search"><input name=btnI type=submit value="I'm Feeling Lucky"></form>
</body>
</html>
```

just stole their form and stuck it in there, should work

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you could use [Google Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome). The address bar is by default a "Google search" box already.

And [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1205/search-box-in-chrome/1320#1320) is how to add feeling lucky